# How to record Oracle FSAL Form Based Application in loadrunner

Tags: loadrunner, oracleforms

I want to record Oracle Form based application FSAL in Loadrunner so which protocol should I use Oracle NCA  right ? And is it possible to record in latest version 24.1 of LR ?
will all form trafic will get record..

Is it same like web or will be encrypted ? Is there anyone who has experience this kind of recording and scripting in LR

Can anyone help me in knowing what things you faced..

Thanks,
Siddhi

As it is POC installations are in progress once it is done will try to record in LR